# AWS RDS Server Over Spec'd?

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds

I wanted to check if my AWS RDS server is over spec'd, it currently costs loads of money and we are trying to reduce our costs.

We are using a db.m5.2xlarge (32 GiB memory / 8 vCPUs / 5000 IOPS).

After using cloudwatch to view some stats i realised that our IOPS seems way to high.

[image: Cloudwatch Graph]

As you can see we never go over 2000 IOPS if you combine read and write.

Our system is constantly being written to every second hence the write IOPS being so high. We only read from the system when someone logs into our portal and runs some reports to view the data. To give some context we are a footfall company who collect town footfall.

We are currently using Provisioned IOPS with 600GB of storage, I'm thinking of switching to General Purpose SSD upping the storage to 1000GB so we get 3000 IOPS just to be safe. Does this seem like a good idea?

I have broke the prices down below and if the performance stays the same this seems like a no brainer.

**Provisioned IOPS**

$348 (3000 IOPS @ $0.116)

$145 (1000GB @ $0.145)

**General Purpose SSD**

$133 (1000GB @ $0.133) this would have 3000 IOPS (3 IOPS x 1GB)

I am yet to look into the memory and vCPUs so this may also need reducing but my main concern right now is the IOPS.

Thanks
Luke

Comment: Changing storage from provisioned to general will also cut your throughput to 160 Mb/s from 320 so I’d ensure that won’t introduce a bottleneck

Comment: @Aaron Thanks for letting me know I just checked and the average spike only hits 47.5M bytes/second so 47.5 Mb/s. Doesnt look like it will cause any issues, would you recommend switching to General Purpose SSD then?

Comment: Based on what you are observing it should be able to maintain the performance. It may take several hours to convert so just be aware that if you do begin to see performance issues it will take some time to change it back

Comment: @Aaron Awesome thank you for letting me know, i really appreciate it.